# How do I get a wx PropertyGrid to allow an IntProperty to be null/None

Tags: wxpython

The [PropertyGrid docs](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_propgrid.html) mention that for any [PGProperty](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_p_g_property.html) you can call [SetAutoUnspecified(true)](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_p_g_property.html#a126a59cc86786f51cc72469bc2143b4c). They say that this should:

> change the property's value to unspecified by modifying the value of the editor control (usually by clearing it). Currently, this can work with following properties: wxIntProperty, wxUIntProperty, wxFloatProperty, wxEditEnumProperty.

However, setting this for an `IntProperty` doesn't work; clearing it and moving the mouse off the cell results either in it being restored to its previous value or a charming message: *You have entered invalid value. Press ESC to cancel editing*

I can get the value to initially be `None`, but how do I allow a user to clear it?

Comment: Tested with the standard wxPython demo's PropertyGrid demo on Windows and GTK...

Comment: Setting validators seemed to either do nothing or crash. I may be doing them wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making my own custom property and editor. This is not perfect but it works.

```py
class NullableIntEditor(propgrid.PyTextCtrlEditor):
    registered = False
    def __init__(self):
        propgrid.PyTextCtrlEditor.__init__(self)

    def CreateControls(self, propGrid, property, pos, sz):
        # Create and populate buttons-subwindow
        wnd = self.CallSuperMethod("CreateControls", propGrid, property, pos, sz)
        wnd.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.OnChar)
        return wnd

    def OnChar(self, event):
        char_code = event.GetUnicodeKey()
        if not char_code or char_code < ord(' '):
            event.Skip()
        char = chr(char_code)
        if (char in '+-' or char.isdigit()):
            event.Skip()


class NullableIntProperty(propgrid.PyProperty):
    def __init__(self, label, name):
        propgrid.PyProperty.__init__(self, label, name)
        self.SetAutoUnspecified(True)

    def GetEditor(self):
        return "NullableIntEditor"

    def ValueToString(self, value, flags):
        return None if value == '' else str(value)

    def StringToValue(self, s, flags):
        """If failed, return False or (False, None). If success, return tuple (True, newValue)."""
        try:
            if not s:
                v = None
            else:
                v = int(s)
            if self.GetValue() != v:
                return (True, v)
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            if flags & propgrid.PG_REPORT_ERROR:
                wx.MessageBox("Cannot convert '%s' into a number." % s, "Error")
            else:
                logging.warning("Cannot convert '%s' into a number.", s)
        return False

    def IntToValue(self, v, flags):
        """If failed, return False or (False, None). If success, return tuple (True, newValue)."""
        if (self.GetValue() != v):
            return (True, v)
        return False

    def ValidateValue(self, value, validationInfo):
        if value == '':
            value = None
        if isinstance(value, int) or value is None:
            return (True, value)
        return False
```